# MsBuild cannot find Godot SDK for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, godot, rider

I am just starting with Godot and I wanted to test de C# support, but when I try to build a project I get an error.

I created a new project, then created a 2DScene and attached a C# script to it.
Next, I tried opening the Godot project from VSCode from the generated `.sln` file.
Here's where it fails, just after opening the project I get the error:
`Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Godot.NET.Sdk/3.3.0' specified could not be found.`

I noticed this was caused by the `.csproj` file that specifies the SDK:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Godot.NET.Sdk/3.3.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I tried the same with Rider and got the same error.

I have Godot-Mono 3.3.3 and the plugins for VSCode and Rider.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Check the build log and see which version of MSBuild you are using first.

Comment: @LexLi how can I see the log?

Comment: Install dotnetcore sdk and use msbuild from it. https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not godot expert, just getting started with it, but I'm not new to dotnet/C#

did notice the same.

You will also note there is no auto-completion/intellisense.

I solved it adding manually the required reference

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="GodotSharp">
    <HintPath>.mono/assemblies/Debug/GodotSharp.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

to the csproj file

I can build the project with `dotnet build`
and I can launch the project directly from VScode

It occurred to me to use the Nuget package, but I found only the Beta 4.x

It seems to me Godot should add the reference into the project template.
Unless I'm missing something :)

Comment: BTW: on Linux,  with the right mono setup there is no need to reference GodotSharp.dll